# How to copy Jenkins VM from one server to another

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, virtual-machine

I'm newbie to Jenkins, have used it, but have never installed one before. Someone who initially did the jenkins installation has left my company, it was running fine, i was able to build; but now, we have got a new server so we have to migrate the Jenkin.

Read in one of links in stackoverflow how people do transfer from one VM to another, by doing new installation of jenkins and then copying the data from old server?

I would like to know if there is no other change in VM and the Ubuntu version used is same across the servers, will I just be able to copy the vm from one server to another server? If that is possible what are all the settings that need to be updated?

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Install Jenkins on new VM, copy jenkins home dir from old to new VM, start jenkins on new VM. Update jenkins url in system config if you are using IP address in jenkins url and it changed

Comment: Hi, I copied as suggested, the server is up and running but i'm not seeing the job, as its in the previous server, and the server rsync failed to copy the entire folder from the other server. The servers port address and the network adapter changed in both cases so it can run in parallel, as its running in different network with different port.

Comment: After a reboot, it started working, thanks for the support